# Open XUL application without navigation bar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have created a XUL dialog, whenever i open this dialog it opens with Firefox navigation bar. Is it possible to open the XUL applications without firefox navigation bar? Screenshot is attached. Iam using Javascript's window.open command. i.e

```
window.open("http://localhost/test.xul", "test", "chrome, width=130,height=60, menubar=no");
```

Here is the XUL code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/global.css" type="text/css"?>
<dialog id="donothing" title="Dialog example"
  xmlns="http://www.mozilla.org/keymaster/gatekeeper/there.is.only.xul"
  buttons="accept,cancel"
  buttonlabelcancel="Cancel"
  buttonlabelaccept="Save"
  ondialogaccept="return doOK();"
  ondialogcancel="return doCancel();">

  <dialogheader title="Options" description="My preferences"/>
  <groupbox>
    <caption label="Colour"/>
    <radiogroup>
      <radio label="Red"/>
      <radio label="Green" selected="true"/>
      <radio label="Blue"/>
    </radiogroup>
    <label value="Nickname"/>
    <textbox/>
  </groupbox>
</dialog>
```

[image: Xulscreenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding "location=no" to the window.open:

```
window.open("http://localhost/test.xul", "test", "chrome, width=130,height=60, menubar=no, location=no");
```

See [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.open?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.open) for reference.

Comment: Thanks for the info, but it didn't work in latest firefox because firefox has disabled it, we can however enable it from about:config.

Comment: @TPSstar - I don't know if it is what you really want, but you could use: `window.openDialog("http://localhost/test.xul","", "all=no","");` See reference [window.openDialog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.openDialog)

Comment: i tried it but javascript gives error 
"SeurityError: The operation is insecure.".

Comment: @TPSstar - hmm. weird. I did it myself and had no errors:
`window.openDialog("chrome://testExt/content/test.xul","", "all=no","");`
Are you loading the xul file from chrome:// ?